# Why I am getting error in this Solidity Code?

Tags: solidity, web3js

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.9;

contract Storage {

   uint number;

    // takes a value _number and assigns it to the state variable number
    function setNumber(uint _number) public {
          number = _number;
    }

    // returns the value of the state variable number
    function getNumber() public view {
        return number;
    }
 }
```

I am getting error in this solidity code in getNumber() function. So, please anyone can explain this or make it correct.

I am unable to understand why I am getting error and I am beginner in solidity.

The error which I am getting is:

> TypeError: Different number of arguments in return statement than in returns declaration.
> --> first.sol:15:9:
> |
> 15 |         return number;
> |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0):

The getNumber function is missing `returns (uint256)`

```
function getNumber() public view returns (uint256) {
    return number;
}
```

Comment: ok thank you
can you please explain why we use "returns (uint256)"

Comment: 'returns' gives the function the ability to return data. the uint256 is return type. more info here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.20/contracts.html#return-variables

Answer (score 0):

@Anbang is right,
You are missing the returns (type) in front of the function.
If you are returning multiple type of variables then it should look like

```
function getNumber() public view returns (uint256, bool) {
    return (number, false);
}
```

the above one is just an example of how you can return multiple types of variables. Use it according to your need.

Also if you plan to practice solidity smart contracts you can visit DApp World platform, there you'll find many assessments.
Link : [Assessments](https://dapp-world.com/assessments)

Comment: Hi Ganesh, this site is not a forum.  We expect each answer to be unique or to add more value.  This adds nothing but waffle.  You havent even explained why this would work.  I havent downvoted it, in the hope that you will improve it.